# How do I integrate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(1+x^2)}{x^{1+\alpha}}dx$ using contour integration?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

The problem I'm trying gives the range $0< \alpha< 2$. What is the contour I should choose?

I think it should depend on $\alpha$ too. I tried using integration by parts to make it more manageable, but it doesn't seem to be helping much.

Comment: At first glance I would guess you should try an indented semicircle (https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikibooks/en/9/9e/ContourSinzz.gif)

Comment: @EthanAlwaise No. see RobertZ's answer.

Comment: Take a look at this Felix Marin's answer. You can easily adapt his proof for your case. http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1097463/186170

Answer (score 1):

Hint. By integrating by parts we obtain
$$I:=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(1+x^2)}{x^{1+\alpha}} dx=\frac{2}{a}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{1-\alpha}}{1+x^2}\,dx.$$
Then by using a keyhole contour and the Cauchy Theorem we get
$$I:=\frac{4\pi i}{\alpha(1-e^{2\pi i(1-\alpha)})}\left(\text{Res}
\left(\frac{z^{1-\alpha}}{1+z^2},i\right)
+\text{Res}\left(\frac{z^{1-\alpha}}{1+z^2},-i\right)\right)=
\frac{\pi}{\alpha\sin(\pi\alpha/2)}.$$