# How to solve the following integral using complex analysis?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How to solve the following integral using residue in complex analysis: $$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln{(1+y^4)}}{1+y^2}dy$$
 Please give a hint. I know that we need to choose a contour in the upper half plane. But here the log term is creating some trouble

Comment: Asked 6 hours before, may be useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3661973/evaluation-of-int-0-pi-2-log-left1-cos2-2x-right-mathrmdx

Comment: I posted an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3663874/) that avoids having to deal with branch points in the upper half-plane.